# free() same heap memory with different pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory, free

```
int main()
{
    int* Pointer;

    Pointer = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *Pointer = 33;

    int* Pointer2 = Pointer;

    printf("%d\n", *Pointer);

    free(Pointer);
    free(Pointer2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 33 with no errors or warnings.
I declared two pointers that are pointing to the same heap address.
I know it's wrong to free them both and it is sufficient to only free one. Is it undefined if I free them both and will it do anything wrong if I free the same heap area from different pointers (`Pointer` and `Pointer2`)?

Comment: It's not OK. Maybe nothing will happen or maybe the system will crash.

Comment: @StoryTeller, the question isn't whether the code performs a double free, but what the effect of that is.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - The dup I suggested asks the same question in different words. I see no difference between asking "is this undefined" and "is this as bad as directly causing UB". But by all means, suggest a better dup. I doubt there's a shortage of them.

Comment: For safety you should null the second pointer. Depending on the system you could access undefined memory.

Comment: @StoryTeller, evidently you and I interpret your proposed dupe differently.  As far as I can tell, your proposed dupe and all the answers to it are focused tightly on the issue of whether a double free is defined in terms of the *value* of the pointer that is freed, or in terms of the *variable* holding that value.  I don't see that as being more than tangentially related to this question, which acknowledges that there is double free, and asks about its *effect*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - *"evidently you and I interpret your proposed dupe differently"* Yes it's obvious we are. But I reiterate: please propose a better one, seeing as this question is asked often enough that I found several options and chose poorly. Assuming of course the purpose of this entire debate is to find a good dup, and not to make sure a low hanging fruit is left up for grabs.

Comment: @StoryTeller, very well, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [C11 standard draft 7.22.3.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is
>   a `null` pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not
>   match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or
>   if the space has been **deallocated by a call to `free`** or `realloc`,
>   the behavior is **undefined**.

(The emphasis is mine..)